# How to remap relative path from Docker container to absolute path in external environment?

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I have a project in c# which has some relative path like "./../../../foo/bar/". 
I have built a container with this project, but when i start it i see an error "File bot found" and this relative path "./../../../foo/bar/some-file.json" in exception message.

How can i run that container whith remapping all files from "./../../../foo/bar/" to "E:\foo\bar\" in my external environment (Windows 10)?

I have tried this command
docker run -p 8899:80 myproj:station72-dev --volume ./../../../foo/bar/:E:\foo\bar\

Comment: try to set `WORKDIR /root/your_project` in your Dockerfile.